# Angular JS Function Accepting Dynamic Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, dynamic, model

I have this HTML

```
<li ng-click="toggleCheckbox('LandDTO.Car.Motor')">
<li ng-click="toggleCheckbox('LandDTO.Car.Motor2')">
```

and here is my function

```
$scope.toggleCheckbox = function (model) {
$scope[model] = true; 
};
```

Its not working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change   `<li ng-click="toggleCheckbox('LandDTO.Car.Motor')">`  to `<li ng-click="toggleCheckbox('Motor')">`

and in function change it to

```
$scope.toggleCheckbox = function (model) {
    $scope.LandDTO.Car[model] = true; 
};
```

Comment: I tried it but it says TypeError: Cannot set property 'Motor' of undefined... Also I tried  $scope.LandDTO.CarDTO[model] = true; , and it also says 'Motor' undefined

Comment: you need to create the object first to assign value to it. so you could try using $scope.LandDto.Car = {model:true}. Assumed you have somewhere in the code have declared $scope.LandDto.Car

Comment: ugh I see, thanks that made me realize a lot of stuff and it kinda makes my approach inefficient. Thanks! learned a lot from this :D